# Локализация/Интернационализация данных из бд(Spring)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, freemarker, локализация

Всем доброго времени суток!Нуждаюсь в Вашем совете)

Мой первый опыт работы со Spring(до этого делал лишь простенькое веб-приложение): при возникновении желания сделать интернационализацию возникла проблема с тем, как изменить отображение списков данных из бд относительно выбранного языка(en/ru/ua). До этого имел опыт работы с jsp, и с помощью:

```
<c:set var="language"
    value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}"
    scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="properties.text" />
...
<fmt:message key="text.login" />
```

всё это дело реализовывал, но это было актуально для статических данных( названия ссылок, надписи на кнопках, и т.д.).
И вот возникла потребность выводить списки данных из бд, фильтровать их (в данном случае: выводить сущности в зависимости от категории, хотел докинуть ещё фильтры на стоимость, наличие акции и т.д.). Ну и столкнулся с проблемой: "как интернационализировать отображение этих списков данных?". Нашёл пару статей и примеров, которые собственно помогли дойти до такого примитивного решения выше упомянутого вопроса => Первая **сущность "MenuItem"**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menu")
public class MenuItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private Long id;

    private String locale;
    private String messagekey;
    private String content;
    private Double price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category type;
//Getters and Setters
```

**вторая сущность "Category"**:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "category")
    public class Category {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
        private Long id;
        private String type;
//Getters and Setters
```

**контролер "MenuController":**

```
@Controller
public class MenuController {

    @Autowired
    private MenuItemRepository menuItemRepository;

    @GetMapping("/menu")
    public String menu(HttpSession session, Model model) {

        String locale = (String) session.getAttribute("lang");

        if (locale == null) {
            session.setAttribute("lang", "ua");
            locale = (String) session.getAttribute("lang");
        }

        List<MenuItem> menuItems = menuItemRepository.findAllByLocale(locale);
        model.addAttribute("menuItems", menuItems);
        return "menu";
    }

    @PostMapping("/menu")
    public String menuFilter(@RequestParam("lang") String locale, Model model, HttpSession session) {

        session.setAttribute("lang", locale);
        List<MenuItem> menuItems = menuItemRepository.findAllByLocale(locale);
        model.addAttribute("menuItems", menuItems);
        System.out.println(locale);
        return "menu";
    }
}
```

**Репозиторий:**

```
public interface MenuItemRepository extends JpaRepository<MenuItem, Long> {

    List<MenuItem> findAllByLocale(String locale);
}
```

**Templates (freemarker):**

```
<#import "parts/common.ftl" as c>
<@c.page>

<div class="card-columns">
    <#list menuItems as menuItem>
    <div class="card my-3">
        <div class="m-2">
        <span>${menuItem.content}</span><br/>
            <i>${menuItem.price}</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    </#list>
</div>
</@c.page>
```

И форма, которая является частью navbar и находится в common.ftl:

```
<form method="post">
            <div class="form-row align-items-center">
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                   <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="lang" onchange="submit()">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose language:</option>
                      <option value="en">English</option>
                      <option value="ru">Русский</option>
                      <option value="ua">Українська</option>
                   </select>
           </div>
           </form>
```

**Ну и собственно содержимое sql файлов:**

```
create table category (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    type varchar(255), 
    primary key (id)
);

create table menu (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    locale varchar(2),
    messagekey varchar(255),
    content varchar(255),
    price double precision,
    category_id bigint,
    primary key (id)
    );

alter table menu
    add constraint menu_category_fk 
    foreign key (category_id) references category (id);


insert into category(id, type) values
    (1, 'Hot dishes'),
    (2, 'Pizza'),
    (3, 'Desserts'),
    (4, 'Salads');

insert into menu(locale, messagekey, content, price, category_id) values
    ('en', 'menu.borsh', 'Borsch', 110, 1),
    ('ua', 'menu.borsh', 'Борщ', 110, 1),
    ('ru', 'menu.borsh', 'Борщ', 110, 1),

    ('en','menu.pepperoni', 'Pepperoni', 140, 2),
    ('ua','menu.pepperoni', 'Пеппероні', 140, 2),
    ('ru','menu.pepperoni', 'Пепперони', 140, 2),

    ('en','menu.berry.pudding', 'Berry pudding', 140, 3),
    ('ua','menu.berry.pudding', 'Ягідний пудинг', 140, 3),
    ('ru','menu.berry.pudding', 'Ягодный пудинг', 140, 3),

    ('en','menu.greek.salad', 'Greek salad', 90, 4),
    ('ua','menu.greek.salad', 'Грецький салат', 90, 4),
    ('ru','menu.greek.salad', 'Салат "Греческий"', 90, 4);
```

**В целом работает, но есть пара проблем:** не придумал ещё как быть с 'category'( по логике вещей нужно тоже этот атрибут отображать в списке, но создавать на каждый язык по три объекта с разными id одной категории, и потом выискивать эти id в записях чтобы эквивалентно их присвоить объектам 'menu' - довольно глупо( хотя если сделать возможность админу через интерфейс сайта добавлять новые сущности в 'menu', выбор категории делать с помощью выведенного списка существующих объектов категорий в зависимости от выбранного языка и брать у них id, то ещё ладно..).

**И вторая:** смущает "адекватность" написанного, да и принцип решения вопроса локализации данных из бд.
Если есть возможность и желание подсказать и наставить на путь истинный, буду крайне вам признателен!
Заранее спасибо!